# How to mock an instantiated class inside a function without dependency injection

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm writing a unit test for a service that use aws-sdk to list all files from s3 bucket.
Inside the function, I instantiate the S3 class and use listObjectsV2 that fetch files from S3 bucket, in the test i should mock this function to return a dummy data.

The problem is that i can't find a way to mock the instantiate class to override the function, i don't want to pass the S3 object in parameter (dependency injection)

aws.service :

```
listAllFiles = (bucket: string, documentsPath: string): Promise<ObjectList> => {
    const params: S3.ListObjectsV2Request = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      EncodingType: 'url',
      StartAfter: documentsPath
    };
    return this.listAllFilesCore(params);
  }

  private listAllFilesCore(params: S3.ListObjectsV2Request): Promise<ObjectList> {
    return new Promise<ObjectList>((resolve, reject) => {
      let result: ObjectList = []; const s3bucket = new S3(this.config);
      s3bucket.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err.message);
          logger.error(err.stack);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          result = result.concat(data.Contents);
          if (data.IsTruncated) {
            logger.debug('get further list...');
            this.listAllFilesCore(Object.assign(params, { ContinuationToken: data.NextContinuationToken }))
              .then(r => {
                result = result.concat(r);
                resolve(result);
              });
          } else {
            logger.debug(`get S3 Success from ${params.StartAfter}`);
            resolve(result);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

```
  let awsService: any;
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
    awsService = require('./aws.service').awsService;
  });

  it('listAllFiles from S3', () => {
    const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
    S3.listObjectsV2 = jest.fn((param: any,
      callback?: (err: any, data: any) => void) => {
      callback(undefined, data2);
    });
```

I get TypeError: s3bucket.listObjectsV2 is not a function

Comment: The purpose of the mocks is to help designing better code. If you cannot mock it, it needs to be redesigned. Not to mention that writing tests after the code does not help the code refactoring (this is one of the purposes of the tests) but obstructs it.

Comment: thanks for your response, so you are confirming that this code is not testable and i should pass the instance in parameter?

Comment: The tested function does not use `this.config` (apart for creating an instance of the `S3` class) and it does not know how to use it anyway. I would definitely inject an `S3` object and not its configuration.

Comment: finally i changed my implementation to inject a mocked version of S3 thank you for the recommandation

Answer (score 0):

You can manually mock the imported module using `jest.mock(moduleName, factory?)` method. Here is the doc: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks